# Replace apache with Nginx as Laravel web server

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

We are current running Laravel with apache as web server and would like to switch to Nginx.

We have Nginx setup but are running into permission problem when trying to switch to Ngnix. Both sessions and cache cannot be written by ngnix.

As work around we tried to put ngnix user in same group as apache then gave write permission on session and cache folders to apache, but this didn't work out.

Another solution  we have tried is run ngnix as using apache user/group but we were not lucky with this either.

Nginx config:

```
# user nginx;
user apache apache;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       <port> default_server;
        listen       [::]:<port> default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         <server root>;


        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        # include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

One of the virtual hosts (server blocks):

```
server {
    listen       <port>;
    root <virtual host folder>;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  <virtual host>;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    } 


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The challenge is getting Nginx to write on session:

```
[2017-04-06 21:35:06] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents(storage/framework/sessions/VkdMhjlYVEi3DvLyK7tQD2tjn8sFFzj2Y8X5erkW): failed to open stream: Permission denied' in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:111
```

Or cache:

```
[2017-04-05 21:47:37] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents(cache/7c/26/7c26fc7024a54df9633e679cfdf19309a84402c7): failed to open stream: Permission denied' in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:111
```

Is it possible to seamlessly switch a running Laravel installation from Apache to Nginx? We are avoiding having to reinstall Laravel afresh.

Comment: It looks like you are running php-fpm for your nginx install.  Check the user the pool you are connecting to runs as.  It will be that user trying to write to the cache files.

Comment: @SymeonQuimby thanks for the tip. You're right, the user is php-fpm. But the same php-fpm is also being Apache without a problem. Does apache bypass php-fpm user and ngnix does not?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing matching apache configs.  Are both apache and nginx setup to serve from the same php-fpm pool?

Comment: There's only 1 php-fpm installation. We used default installation without any changes to the configuration. So, I will assume both apache and nginx use the same. Does apache have a separate php-fpm configuration?

Comment: @SymeonQuimby We did not do any special config on apache to use php-fpm. It rans php-fpm out of the box. So, I will assume both apache and nginx use the same php-fpm pool.  How else can one verify this?

Comment: Changing user on php-fpm to apache resolves the problem but it's not clear why this doesn't affect apache